# "Cannot return a value from method whose result type is void"

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, return

How can I use the boolean hasDivisor outside the for loop? I get the message "Cannot return a value from method whose result type is void" when I try to compile this section of the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumBox.length; i++) 
                {
                 if (NumBox[i] == 0) 
                    continue;
                 boolean hasDivisor = false;
                 for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

                    if (NumBox[j] == 0) 
                     continue;
                     if (NumBox[i] % NumBox[j] == 0) {
                       hasDivisor = true;
                       break;
                    }
                 }
                 return hasDivisor;
              }
```

Comment: Your method needs to have a result type of `boolean` instead of `void`. This is pretty basic Java, so you may want to read a book or online tutorial. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html for this specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you should do:

```
boolean hasDivisor = false;

for (int i = 0; i < NumBox.length; i++) 
            {
             if (NumBox[i] == 0) 
                continue;
             hasDivisor = false;
             for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

                if (NumBox[j] == 0) 
                 continue;
                 if (NumBox[i] % NumBox[j] == 0) {
                   hasDivisor = true;
                   break;
                }
             }
```

You were declaring the hasDivisor variable inside the loop, wich makes it scoped only for the loop. To access it, you shoudl declare it outside.

Answer (score 2):

First problem: Variables have a *scope* that's limited to the *block* in which they're declared. Your variable is declared *within* the for loop, but you want to use it *outside* the loop. Declare it *outside* (ie before) the loop.

Second problem: Declare your method to return `boolean` - judging by the error message, it's currently declared to return `void`